# How do I efficiently perform collision detection on an NxN rectangle grid?

Tags: collision-detection, grid

I have a simple level that is constructed from an NxN rectangle grid. Some of the rectangles are walls, and some of them are the path. The player is allowed to move only on the path they are on and also the path rectangles on the grid. So I have two kinds of rectangles in the grid:

1. "path"
2. "wall"

The player is a sprite above the grid. I want to efficiently find if the player is colliding with the wall. I want to loop through the rectangles, to see if they intersect. What is the best method?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is probably not calculating anything. You can "precalculate" collision simply by drawing the wall "a bit smaller". Just subtract half of player *r* from the wall, the wall is still "physically" on whole tile but its image just don't reach its edges. Floor the float value of your player position, query grid matrix...and done!

```
inline bool isCollision()
{
    return (grid[(int)player.x, (int)player.y] is Wall);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your grid is represented as a 2d array of booleans (0 for path, 1 for wall) or integers (n for path, m for wall), and the player is smaller than the tiles, you need to check if any of the four corners of the player are inside a wall.

If the center of the player's "square" is `x, y` and the width is `w` then you need to check in

```
(x - width/2,  y - width/2) // top left
(x + width/2,  y - width/2) // top right
(x - width/2,  y + width/2) // bottom left
(x + width/2,  y + width/2) // bottom right
```

You check if a point is inside a tile by dividing that point's `x, y` position by a tile's width and height and then check if there is a tile in the resulting position in the 2d array that represents the tiles.

```
checkCollision(x, y)
{
    tileX = Math.floor(x / TILE_WIDTH);
    tileY = Math.floor(y / TILE_HEIGHT);
    tile = grid[tileX][tileY];
    return isWall(tile);
}
```

Comment: i didint understand how get i know the grid right tile to check
after i have my player size

Comment: The answer assumes your grid of tiles is a 2d array of int, in which case the correct tile would be in: ... `gridArrayName[x / TILE_WIDTH][y / TILE_HEIGHT]`. If you are not using a 2d array to represent your tiles, you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the area covered by the played in a grid.

If you consider each wall a position inside a grid, you only need to check the collision against the cells occupied by the player.

If you consider your player has a size of 1x1, you can know in which cell of the grid your player falls into if you divide it's position between the size of each cell.

So if you player is in position (12,9), and your cells are 5x5 units in size:

(12,9)/5 = (2,1)

Since you start counting in 0, the player would be in the third cell in the second row.

If you are storing your cell information inside a matrix you should only check collision against position [2,1].

The same applies if the player cover a bigger area: Just check which cells cover the corners of your player.

Comment: sorry i dont understand how this should work